# Create PDF for current worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. I want to be able to create a single pdf for the currently selected worksheet (not all active worksheet). Selected as in the worksheet I'm on.

I have the below code. My worksheet names changes often as well so referring to a specific name will not work.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Dim CurWorksheet As Worksheet
    For Each CurWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        CurWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & CurWorksheet.Name, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next CurWorksheet
    MsgBox ("PDF saved")
End Sub
```

Comment: replace `CurWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat ...` with `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat...` that is all you need. You can remove the loop and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ActiveSheet` property which returns an object that represents the active sheet (the sheet on top) in the active workbook or in the specified window or workbook.

```
Sub SaveActiveSheetAsPDF()   
     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & CurWorksheet.Name, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox ("PDF saved")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help! I'm getting a Run-tim error '424'Object required. Do you know how to solve this?